# Hand him (odd phrase)

Tags: meaning, phrases

> ... telling Voldemort you could **hand him** the Potters.

My research: I scoured online dictionaries only to find it always means "give something by hand".
So please consider citing a dictionary if you get the correct definition.
I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

**hand** (v.)

> To present or provide with [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hand)

> To give, pass or transmit with the hand, literally or
> **figuratively**. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hand)

> **In extended use**: to deliver, pass on; to transfer, transmit.  to hand (also give) (something) to (a person) on a plate
>
> *Adventurers and scholars and fishermen began to question the truths about the world **handed to them** from earlier generations.*
>
> *The kind words **handed to them** from every side were richly deserved.* OED

---

> By 1974, a district court in Fukuoka **handed him** a victory. [Naoko
> Wake; *American Survivors*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Survivors/aVctEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22handed%20him%20a%20victory%22&pg=PA295&printsec=frontcover)

> Then September **handed them** a surprise. Early the next morning Willie
> Joe called. “A woman named Miss Flora said you need yo house lifted. I kin do the job iffen you want."
> [Maxwell Dickinson; *A Country Mile*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Country_Mile/vL96Rswz2hMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22handed%20them%20a%20surprise%22&pg=PA174&printsec=frontcover)

> Yet he also **handed them** a solution, pegging criminality to
> informality and both to the element that had created the trade and had
> been devised to do what it was obviously failing to do: the taxi
> license. [Juan Manuel del Nido; *Taxis vs. Uber*](https://books.google.com/books?id=y2tEEAAAQBAJ&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PT69&dq=%22handed%20them%20a%20solution%22&hl=en&source=newbks_fb#v=onepage&q=%22handed%20them%20a%20solution%22&f=false)

> They wanted Robert Kennedy off their backs, and what better way to do
> that than by getting rid of the man who'd **handed him power on a
> plate**—JFK
> [RW Press Ltd; *JFK Assassination*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/JFK_Assassination/cPCnf479OkUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=handed%20them%20on%20a%20plate%20JFK&pg=PT6&printsec=frontcover)

> "The destinies of the world were **handed them on a plate** in 1920."
> [Herbert C. Pell, quoted in A. M. Schlesinger; *The Crisis of the Old
> Order, 1919-1933*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Crisis_of_the_Old_Order_1919_1933/UAjls3YykzgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=who%20had%20handed%20them%20on%20a%20plate&pg=PA397&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: I have to hand it to you, this answer is thorough.

Comment: I got curious about exactly what kinds of things you can *hand someone* figuratively.  We also use *hand over* figuratively and literally. *Hand off* is usually *to transfer* in general, and used literally in American football.